# Can we get back our money after successful transaction but API fails in in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

- In my app after transaction is successful ,My API call is getting
  failed.
- In this case can I refund the amount to  the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call the `finishTransaction:` method on the `SKPaymentQueue` after your API call has completed.  If you don't call this method then Apple will consider the purchase as incomplete and will re-deliver the transaction the next time your app starts.  Essentially the flow should be:

1. Submit an `SKPayment` onto the `SKPaymentQueue` via `addPayment`
2. Wait for the queue observer to receive a transaction state of `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`
3. Call your API to unlock/deliver content
4. Once that call has succeeded call `finishTransaction` on the `SKPaymentQueue`
5. If your API fails at step 3 then retry until it succeeds
6. If your app restarts with a pending transaction then the transaction will be re-delivered as in step 2

Refer to the [in-app purchase programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3) - you should add a payment observer to the queue as soon as your app starts. The observer will receive any incomplete transactions when the app starts - so if you don't call `finishTransaction` you will get another opportunity.

Comment: In transaction state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased,if network failure occurs and my api is not able to be called but the amount is deducted from  my account   what will happen?will Apple throw any alert ?

Comment: What will happen if we will not write                   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

Comment: Apple will keep posting the transaction to your queue observer until you call `finishTransaction`.

Comment: Sorry ,I did not understand your ans.Can you please write the full sentence/line of code ?